# How to align text parts with different font size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to type some texts aligned in the center. Each phrase is supposed to have a different text size, to try and have the same exact visual width of the previous one, and so on.

This is an example of how it has to be: http://soluzionipersuasive.com/img/text.png

I'm using this code in the CSS part:

```
.a1 {
    font-family: Alfa Slab One;
    color: blue;
    font-size:35px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    }

.b2 {
    font-family: Alfa Slab One;
    color: #0585c0;
    font-size:40px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    }

.c3 {
    font-family: Alfa Slab One;
    color: blue;
    font-size:40px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    }
```

... and this other one in the html zone:

```
<span class="a1">Hello <span class="b2">How are you? <span class="c3">All good!</span>
```

But unfortunately the code isn't working. It is only providing the correct text color. Text font and font size of each text takes the same as the first one. Can't understand why.

Any tips?

Comment: You can't do that with CSS (except fiddling around with the font sizes which won't be responsive or font-independent), but there is a jQuery plugin which can do things like that: http://fittextjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use display flex and align the items center. It also helps to close spans.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.a1 {
    font-family: Alfa Slab One;
    color: blue;
    font-size:35px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    }

.b2 {
    font-family: Alfa Slab One;
    color: #0585c0;
    font-size:40px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    }

.c3 {
    font-family: Alfa Slab One;
    color: blue;
    font-size:40px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    }
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <span class="a1">Hello</span> 
  <span class="b2">How are you? </span>
  <span class="c3">All good!</span>
</div>
```

Not sure what exactly you're after - this could be it as well:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.a1 {
    font-family: Alfa Slab One;
    color: blue;
    font-size:35px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    }

.b2 {
    font-family: Alfa Slab One;
    color: #0585c0;
    font-size:40px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    }

.c3 {
    font-family: Alfa Slab One;
    color: blue;
    font-size:40px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    }
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <span class="a1">Hello</span> 
  <span class="b2">How are you? </span>
  <span class="c3">All good!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<span>` display your content in a single line is you want to break line using span you have to apply css to span look the snippet code for more understanding.

```css
.title_center_box {
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.title_center_box span{
  display: block;
}
.a1 {
  font-family: Alfa Slab One;
  color: blue;
  font-size:35px;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}

.b2 {
  font-family: Alfa Slab One;
  color: #0585c0;
  font-size:40px;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}

.c3 {
  font-family: Alfa Slab One;
  color: blue;
  font-size:40px;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="title_center_box">
  <span class="a1">Hello</span>
  <span class="b2">How are you?</span>
  <span class="c3">All good!</span>
</div>
```

I think this will work please try this code.

Thank You.